# GREP duplicate line of text

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, batch-processing, grep

Is it possible to duplicate lines of text with GREP? Here is exactly what I would like to do; I have a list of letters and numbers that looks like this:

> R1H3BOA2HA4
>
> R1H3BOA2H4
>
> R1H2H3BO4

And I need it to be like this:

> R1H3BOA2HA4=R1+H3+BOA2+HA4
>
> R1H3BOA2H4=R1+H3+BOA2+H4
>
> R1H2H3BO4=R1+H2+H3+BO4

So basically I would like to duplicate every line, add the = symbol between the original and the copy and then add + after the numbers of the copy except for the last number. I understand how GREP works but I’m very bad with the syntax.
Any idea? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the pattern to match
this matches any character one or more times followed by a number (repeated 4 times), the parentheses saves that value then you can recall those saved values with $ and then the corresponding number of the saved value e.g first $1 second $2

([\l\u]+?\d)([\l\u]+?\d)([\l\u]+?\d)([\l\u]+?\d)

this is your replace
$1$2$3$4=$1+$2+$3+$4

using indesigns grep menu the (@) symbol in the find and replace dialog can help with the syntax